# Using the AWS java SDK to return a AmazonEC2 with environment variables?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I've been successfully using the Java SDK, with a ~/.aws/credentials file to be back an AmazonEc2 instance as follows:

```
private AmazonEC2 getEc2Client() {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();

    AmazonEC2 amazonEC2 = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);
    Region govCloud = Region.getRegion(Regions.GovCloud);
    amazonEC2.setRegion(govCloud);

    return amazonEC2;
}
```

However I now want to switch to using environment variables, instead of the file. I have my environment variables set, but I can't figure out the code to do it with. An example (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html) shows the following:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                       .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
                       .build();
```

But that returns an AmazonS3 instead of an AmazonEC2. I try the below:

```
    AmazonEC2 amazonEC2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())
        .build();
```

But there is no such thing as an "AmazonEC2ClientBuilder"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed an [AmazonEC2ClientBuilder](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.html).

Some example usage from the [aws-sdk-java samples](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/src/samples/AmazonEC2SpotInstances-GettingStarted/Requests.java):

```
AmazonEC2 ec2 = null;

/*
 * The ProfileCredentialsProvider will return your [default]
 * credential profile by reading from the credentials file located at
 * (~/.aws/credentials).
 */
AWSCredentials credentials = null;
try {
        credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials();
} catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AmazonClientException(
                "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                "location (~/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
                e);
}

ec2 = AmazonEC2ClientBuilder.standard()
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
        .withRegion("us-west-2")
        .build();
```

The code in your question looks as though it would work appropriately.

Comment: Well the code you have is for loading it with the credentials. The code I had actually did end up working correctly, but I had an old version of aws SDK. I updated the version then it worked